# Why <type 'Null' is not a subtype of type 'String'> error doesn't appear in debug (Flutter)

Tags: json, flutter, dart

So I developing app on Flutter, and I wrote this code bellow. I figured out that our BE doesn't returns language field sometimes, so it need to be marked as optional. But question is, why when I working in vscode in debug mode, it's say nothing about it, but when I create ipa or apk file, run it on physical device, it's throw error on attempt to "serialize" this model? I'm attaching a screenshot of the error as well.

[image: Error]

```
class User {
  late int id;
  late String firstName;
  late String lastName;
  late String? birthdate;
  late bool showBirthDate;
  late UserStatus status;
  late String description;
  late String phone;
  late String email;
  late String language;
  late String image;

  User({
    required this.id,
    required this.firstName,
    required this.lastName,
    required this.birthdate,
    required this.showBirthDate,
    required this.status,
    required this.description,
    required this.phone,
    required this.email,
    required this.language,
    required this.image,
  });

  User.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    id = json['id'];
    firstName = json['firstName'];
    lastName = json['lastName'];
    birthdate = json['date_of_birth'];
    showBirthDate = json['show_birth_date'] == 10;
    status = UserStatus.fromStaus(json['status']);
    description = json['description'];
    phone = json['phone'];
    email = json['email'];
    language = json['language'];
    image = json['image'];
  }
}
```

I trying to figure out how to get <type 'Null' is not a subtype of type 'String'> error in debug mode.

Comment: are you testing the app in debug mode using the same dataset as in production?

Comment: @NirmalCode, yep.

Comment: Can you share the code related to displaying that alert?

Comment: @NirmalCode, I'm got catchError block on Future statement. Handle Error function show PlatformDialogue.


```.catchError((error) {
      handleError(error, context);
    })
```

Comment: `status = UserStatus.fromStaus(json['status']);`

Comment: have you added the internet permission ?

Answer (score 0):

Check for null and typecast as you load your JSON

```dart
 id = int.tryParse(json['id']?.toString() ?? '0') ?? 0;
 firstName = json['firstName']?.toString() ?? 'First';
 lastName = json['lastName']?.toString() ?? 'Last';
```

Comment: I'm totally understand how to solve it. My question is "how debug it". In debug mode app say nothing about this fields. But when I create apk or ipa file, it's start throw it.

Comment: Oh I see. If you are using VSCode, do you have 'All Exceptions' checked under breakpoints?

Comment: yep. Also I got one on 'uncaught exception'